# Support id3v2 tags pictures for each individual song file

Tags: id3v2

I would like to attach a different image to each song in an album. However, as my album is a collection of interviews, I would like to be able to attach a different image to all these interviews.

As I've been reading spec, there are support image types:

- $00     Other
- $01     32x32 pixels 'file icon' (PNG only)
- $02     Other file icon
- $03     Cover (front)
- $04     Cover (back)
- $05     Leaflet page
- $06     Media (e.g. lable side of CD)
- $07     Lead artist/lead performer/soloist
- $08     Artist/performer
- $09     Conductor
- $0A     Band/Orchestra
- $0B     Composer
- $0C     Lyricist/text writer
- $0D     Recording Location
- $0E     During recording
- $0F     During performance
- $10     Movie/video screen capture
- $11     A bright coloured fish
- $12     Illustration
- $13     Band/artist logotype
- $14     Publisher/Studio logotype

Problem is that if I pick up e.g. Cover (front), all songs in an album use the same image (from the first song in the album) and my Android Music player does not distinguish images.

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Attaching different covers to each individual song is not a problem. Just use a program like [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/index.html). You can drag & drop your image to the matching song. (I do that for Top 20 Single-Charts where every Single has is own front cover image. All this 20 songs are in the same directory with a date as directory name.

If your Android Music player doesn't read each image from each file, you can only switch to another music player. I don't see any other solution with the help of id3tags.

Comment: Thank you, however I do not have any Windows machine. May I ask you for uploading a couple of a free mp3 files, which I can grab and identify picture type?

Comment: Mp3tag also runs with WINE. Or what kind of OS do you use?

Comment: Works for me, as I observed the output it uses Cover as image type.